# Remove local changes from repository

Tags: git

So. Annoying.

Edited for brevity:

```
$ git pull origin master
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/models/page.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at d90309f 
$ git pull origin master
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/models/page.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting

$ git rm --cached
usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched

$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/Jinxy5/laughing-octo-lana
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/models/page.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
$ git rm --cached app/models/page.rb
fatal: pathspec 'app/models/page.rb' did not match any files
```

Answers to similar questions state `git rm --cached` will fix the problems, but am I doing it wrong? Because it says it didn't match any files? Maybe because I ran git reset?

Comment: Do I substitute the `u` for a commit id? I did that and it did nothing sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
git clean -fd
```

Comment: Glad to help! May be you could accept this answer then?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a look at this post i came up recently to know clearly on removing local changes

[Various ways to remove local Git changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620393/git-remove-local-changes)

"Conclusion:

It's clear that we can use either

(1) combination of `git clean -f` and `git reset --hard` 
OR

(2) `git stash -u`
to achieve the desired result.

```
git clean -f -d  "
```