# Git - Can not remove one auto-modified file

Tags: git, github, version-control

This sound basic question and duplicate of [Remove local Git changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620393/various-ways-to-remove-local-git-changes) most likely. However, I did try many option but could not get a clean slate. I am heading to create a new branch but I get error:

```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
> by checkout:
>        js/us-states.xml 
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches. Aborting
```

Since I have not modified this file (it got automatically modified) I need to discard the changes. Seems like it shown modified due to LF-CRLF conversion. I am on Windows machine.

I tried:

1. git checkout .
2. git clean -f
3. git reset --hard
4. git stash -u
5. git gui > Revert changes

But no matter what command I run, as soon as I run git status it show me this output:

> D:\GitHub\Project>git status On branch master Your branch is
>   up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>     modified:   js/us-states.xml
> ```
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I am getting into such issues frequently now a days. One or the other way I solve it but like to know what's going on and is there a permanent solution for this issue.

Why it does not let me discard the changes for this file?

**Update 1:**

As a work around, I committed the change (not pushed) to get a clean slate as desired when I run git status. I was able to switch to another branch. Later I ran

git reset --hard origin/master

this in effect, removed temp local commit.