# Filetree is not refreshing after switching branches - cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, cloud9-ide, c9.io

In cloud9 IDE, I am doing simple rails app in master branch. I decided to experiment a little, so I created new branch like this:

```
git checkout -b experiment-branch
```

Then I created some controllers, models etc. but experiment fails and I do not committed it. However I dont't want to delete this branch, so I tried to go back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

and code (controllers, models etc) from the previous experiment was still there in filetree, ApplicationController etc.

I tried `git reset --soft <desired-previous-commit-hash>` but it not worked.

I assume the second command should return me the state of my app from before creating the branch `experiment-branch`. Am I right or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not tracked the new files you add in the `experiment-branch` - these are still lying around as untracked files.

Untracked files are not removed when you change branches.

You would need to clean them to remove the untracked files. use `git clean -n` (dry-run) to identify all the files that are untracked.

Then you could `git clean -f` to clean all the file shown in the dry-run. Or you could use the interactive mode `git clean -I`

To revert changes from tracked files, use `git checkout .`

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620393/various-ways-to-remove-local-git-changes) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for answer but that's not what I mean. I have used `git clean -n` & `-f` and all files 100% related to `exp.branch` has gone but code from this branch in files like `application_controller.rb` is still there. What I wanted is to get back to state of the app just before creating this exp.branch like it never happened (with leaving this branch just for review)