# Not able to switch back to branch which is ahead of current branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I was working in a branch "test" and took pull and now I am updated as per origin.

```
git checkout develop
```

I checkout to branch "develop" which is behind origin/develop and I copy made some changes in code. Now I run:

```
 git status
```

I got many untracked file and not staged files as I was ahead when I working in branch "test". Now I just want to checkout back to test branch and push my changes.
My changes are little so I can revert and redo them.
But how to switch branch because I get error:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>
> **All untsaged and untracked files**
>
> Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
>
> Aborting

Need help so that I can get back to test branch and redo my changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checkout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this situation stash is your best friend - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Here is an example of how you can resolve it, I have gone from the step when you checked out develop

```
git checkout develop
git stash 
git checkout test
git stash pop
git add .
git commit -m 'YOUR MESSAGE'
git checkout develop
```

that should do it for you!

Comment: Thanks a ton @josh for taking time out to answer this. 
I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620393/various-ways-to-remove-local-git-changes/44761452
to find solution to my problem and similar to ur solution I used 
git checkout . and git stash -u and git checkout test.