# Apply stash to different branch

Tags: git, git-stash

I was accidentally working on the wrong branch. Now I want to transfer all my changes to the correct branch.

If I stash the changes and apply them on the correct branch, will it only add the uncommitted changes to the correct branch or every change/commit from the wrong branch that doesn't exist on the correct branch?

**For example**

Wrong branch has:

- Commit a
- Uncommitted Changes b

Correct branch has

- Commit c

If I do git stash on the wrong branch and git apply stash in the correct branch, will it transfer commit a to the correct branch?

Comment: Nope. Commit a won't be transfer

Answer (score 15):

I would do one stash, then reset (mixed so you don't lose the changes) the a commit, stash that, then change to the correct branch and pop both stashes.

```
git stash save "b"
git reset HEAD~
git stash save "a"
git checkout correct-branch
git stash pop
git commit -m "a"
git stash pop
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing? I don't understand why you do `git reset HEAD~
git stash save "a"
`

Comment: @likejudo the reset step moves the git to the previous commit, then stash it as "a"

Answer (score 15):

If your branch doesn't exist yet:

- git stash branch "new_branch"

if it does:

- git stash
- git stash branch "temp_new_branch"
- git add "your changes"
- git commit
- git checkout "your desired branch to apply stash"
- git merge "temp_new_branch"
- git push
- git branch -d "temp_new_branch"

Comment: `no stash entries found` when I try `git stash branch "temp_new_branch"
`

Comment: If anyone can look at that second option, and still love git... Well, you and I would not get along...

Comment: @spechter well... any alternatives? I don't think love has anything to do with it. It's still the most efficient solution (for now). Besides, this is an issue specific to stashes, which are "sort of" a parallel reality to your work flow. So the fact that there is a workflow to solve something, I think that's great.

Answer (score 6):

**Workaround**

1. Make a commit with those desired changes.
2. Checkout to the branch you want those changes to be on.
3. From that branch `git cherry-pick 23h123kjb`(<-- replace this hash with the one found in a `git log` specific to the commit you want to bring in)
4. Profit!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you end up committing unrelated work to the first branch!

Comment: Wouldn't call it a 'problem'. Can easily reset to previous commit on first branch.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. Commits are not put in the Stash.
I also sometimes just switch branches with my changes uncommitted and unstashed and it also works (not sure if in every case, though).

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do:

- Create a patch on the 'wrong' branch.
- Discard the changes
- Switch to the correct branch
- Apply the patch on that branch