# How do I switch from a merged branch to an new branch?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally started working on a merged branch, now I want go back to develop get the updated code and then create a new branch. Is it possible to do so, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following commands:

`git stash`: It will stash your uncommited changes.

`git checkout develop`: Go to develop branch

`git pull`: Get the latest code

`git checkout -b "new branch"`  : Create a new branch

`git stash apply` : It will add your uncommited changes made in the step 1

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna undo commits check this: [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

if you just want to change branch and create a new branch run this in terminal:

git checkout -b (write the name you want)

by running this you will create a new branch and also will switch to it.

Comment: if I create a new branch from this merged feature branch that will mess up the workflow. If my work was limited to a couple of files I could maybe copy those changes, stash my code and then got to develop and then create a new branch, but I've got a lot of changes that I accidentally started writing in this branch (no commits done).

Comment: just stash and the pop in new branch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417792/apply-stash-to-different-branch